# Getting a url not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

When I start my project in VS13 it tries to navigate to:

```
http://localhost:3918/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

Here it reports:  `Server Error in '/' Application` and says the resource cannot be found.

I have to manually delete: `Views/Home/Index.cshtml` in the url, so that it only says: `http://localhost:3918`. Then it will work. How can I go about this? I have tried to click on the entire WebApplication, and said "Set as startUp project", and I have also tried to set the index.cshtml as startup, but nothing works.

This url: `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` actually does exist, even though it says that it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC urls are not directly pointing to the the view files, as usually happens in ASP.NET. Here everything works through routing, and url should typically be in form "example.com/{controller}/{action}"

Comment: You dont navigate to a file, you navigate to a controller method that returns the view, for example  `http://localhost:3918/Home/Index`

Comment: My Action method says return View()
I have also tried to change it to: return View("~/Home/Index"); But no matter what I change, it still tries to access: http://localhost:3918/Views/Home/Index.cshtml on startup

Answer (score 1):

You have set a specific page to run hence VS is loading it as static file.

Go to project properties > Web > Change to Current Page.

What you have got:

[image: wrong option]

What you should have:

[image]

Comment: Or as I do just have this as as forward slash if you want to go to the home page every time.

Comment: Nik0lias - Your default route would take you there. Am I missing your point?